# Xamarin Forms Binding Issues using Mvvm Light

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding, mvvm-light

Good afternoon everyone. I have just begun to work with Xamarin Forms as I will need it for my job and wanted to learn best practices from the beginning so I went for Mvvm Light. My current problem is that, whatever I do, I really can't make binding work (NOTE: it worked for my first project, a simple page where I had a button which was used to navigate to another page). Now, for my current project, an EventApp I tried everything I could, looking on lots of forums and tried various settings and implementations but couldn't make the binding work again. I will show you some of my current code for a test page I've done just for testing purposes.

App.cs class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static ViewModelLocator _locator;
    public static ViewModelLocator Locator { get { return _locator ?? (_locator = new ViewModelLocator()); } }

    public App()
    {  
       InitializeComponent() //Tried both with and without this
       registerNavigationService();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }

    public void registerNavigationService()
    {
        NavigationService nav = new NavigationService();
        nav.Configure(PageNames.GeneralNotificationPage, typeof(GeneralNotificationPage));
        nav.Configure(PageNames.CreateNotificationPage, typeof(CreateNotificationPage));
        nav.Configure(PageNames.SelectSongPage,typeof(SelectSongPage));
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => nav);
        var firstPage = new NavigationPage(new SelectSongPage());
        nav.Initialize(firstPage);
        MainPage = firstPage;
    }
}
```

`
App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="EventAppMvvm.App"
    >

</Application>
```

-Note: here I tried to set a static resource for my ViewModelLocator the next way:

```
xlmns:vm="clr-namespace:EventAppMvvm.ViewModel;assembly=EventAppMvvm"
```

and then in resources

```
<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
```

doesn't work, if I try in one of my pages to set the DataContext, it says it hasn't found any bindable property. If I set the BindingContext to that I get an NPE when I run the app as there is no object created. So I ended up using the code behind to do the BindingContext and instantiate the locator in my App.cs file so I won't receive an NPE.

ViewModelLocator:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
    /// </summary>
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        ////if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        ////{
        ////    // Create design time view services and models
        ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
        ////}
        ////else
        ////{
        ////    // Create run time view services and models
        ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
        ////}

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CreateNotificationPageViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SelectSongPageViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<GeneralNotificationPageViewModel>();


    }

    public CreateNotificationPageViewModel CreateNotificationPageVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CreateNotificationPageViewModel>();
        }
    }
    public SelectSongPageViewModel SelectSongPageVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SelectSongPageViewModel>();
        }
    }
    public GeneralNotificationPageViewModel GeneralNotificationPageVM
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<GeneralNotificationPageViewModel>();
        }
    }

    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // TODO Clear the ViewModels
    }
}
```

One of my ViewModels(test one):

```
public class SelectSongPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    RelayCommand _commandTest;
    Song _selectedSong;
    INavigationService navigation;
    string clicked = "3";
    string _message = "I ve not been clicked yet";

    public SelectSongPageViewModel(INavigationService navigation)
    {
        this.navigation = navigation;          
    }


    RelayCommand CommandTest 
    {
        get 
        {
            if(_commandTest == null) 
            {
                _commandTest= new RelayCommand(() => 
                {
                    Message = _message;
                    //navigation.NavigateTo(PageNames.CreateEventPage);
                });
            }
            return _commandTest;
        }
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get 
        {
            return clicked;
        }
        set 
        { 
            clicked = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Message");
        }
    }
}
```

Actual page of that ViewModel:
 Notes: if I try to use DataContext (defined as static resource previously in App.xaml), no matter if I give the correct namespace and assembly, it says that it hasn't found any binding, property there, if I use BindingContext, it works, I don't get any errors at compile time but I can't make the buttons do something as it is like it doesn't recognize my defined commands but for some reason it just binds simple data like my Message property.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="EventAppMvvm.Views.SelectSongPage"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
   >
    <ContentPage.Content>
         <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Message}"></Label>
            <Button Text="Press me"  Command="{Binding CommandTest}"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And the code behind for this page.

```
namespace EventAppMvvm.Views
{
    public partial class SelectSongPage : ContentPage
    {
        public SelectSongPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var vm = App.Locator.SelectSongPageVM;
            BindingContext = vm;
        }
    }
}
```

Whatever I do, I can't make the commands/Complex binding work again for some reason but still simple property binding works, I'm using VisualStudio for Mac if it matters.

Comment: Your `RelayCommand CommandTest` appears to be private (because it is not declared `public` explicity). You said that the binding `Text="{Binding Message}"` already works, so adding the `public` keyword to the `CommandTest` property should fix your binding issue